# Python : API, edited file is not formatted correctly

Tags: python, api, put

I am trying to append text to a file programmatically via API.

Here is my code:

```
def updateFile(fileId):
   headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'token': token  
   }
   url = 'https://example.com/api/file/' + str(fileId) + '/upload'
   te = """
      this
      is
      text
      sdfs
   """
   te= json.dumps(te)
   return requests.put(url, headers=headers, data=te)
r = updateFile(id)
print r.json()
```

This is working, But when I download the file, I have some string like this:

```
"\n      this\n      is\n      text\n      sdfs\n   "
```

As you can see, all the text is on the same line (`\n` is not interpreted correctly), The `"` still exists.

What can I be doing wrong?

Comment: Are you viewing the file on windows? http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~krueger/csc209h/tut/line-endings.html

Comment: ...Are you sure the file content has to be json encoded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Send the raw file content without JSON encoding it, but don't specify `Content-Type: application/json`.

By setting that header you're telling the server that the body of the request will be in JSON format which, if you upload the file as is, it will not be. The server is expecting JSON but is unhappy when it does not get JSON data. Conversely, if you send JSON data with that header, the server accepts the data and writes it to the file without decoding it.

You might need to set the content type. Assuming a plain text file you could use `text/plain`.

---

If you take a look at the result of `json.dumps()`:

```
import json

te = """
      this
      is
      text
      sdfs
   """
>>> json.dumps(te)
'"\\n      this\\n      is\\n      text\\n      sdfs\\n   "'
```

you'll see that the new lines are escaped so that they are preserved. That's why they appear in your file. If you don't want them in your file then don't treat the string as JSON data, just upload it as is.

---

BTW, you can avoid the hassle of converting to JSON yourself if you use the `json` parameter instead of the `data` parameter:

```
# do not manually convert to JSON, use json parameter instead
return requests.put(url, headers=headers, json=te)
```

Comment: The API needs te to JSON.

Comment: @dmx: then pass JSON as you are doing (or use the `json` parameter as per my recommendation). In practice you would usually pass a dictionary with some identifying key and the value containing your data. e.g. `requests.put(url, headers=headers, json={'content': te})`

Comment: When I use json={'content': te}, I get this `{"content": "\n      this\n      is\n      text\n   yep\n   "}`

Comment: @dmx: that's the content of the file created on the server? Your string contains new line characters which must be preserved. If the server (API) requires the file content to be JSON encoded then it should be decoding it before persisting to file. It's unusual to expect that a file be JSON encoded for upload and I doubt that the API requires that. Why do you think that you need to JSON encode it? Do you have a spec?

Comment: sorry for responding late. I think API is waiting for json because when I send a string, I receive this message: `{u'error': u'[JSON] Syntax invalid'}`, But When I send JSON, it seems to work.

Comment: @dmx: Other than the surrounding quotes a JSON encoded string is not really distinguishable from a plain string. What API are you using and is there a specification, or even source code, available?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154768/discussion-between-dmx-and-mhawke).

Comment: @dmx: I've updated my answer with a probable cause and fix.